# How to handle prompt box with Robot Framework?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework with Selenium2Library for website tests automation. In one of the cases there is a prompt box (pop-up similar to alert, but with an input field in it, see [example here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt)) asking for some text. The problem is Robot Framework can only click OK or Cancel (Confirm Action and Choose Cancel On Next Confirmation keywords) on such pop-ups. So the question is: how can I input some text into the prompt box? Is it possible?

In SeleniumLibrary there was a Press Key Native keyword which could press keys without specifying the target element, but it is absent in Selenium2Library. If you know of any alternative - your answer will be much appreciated.

Using AutoIT isn't an option as the tests could be run on different platforms (not only Win).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selenium2Library doesn't currently have support for inserting text into a prompt. I've opened an issue in the issue tracker for this:

https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/issues/292

Until it gets added, you can create your own selenium library by subclassing Selenium2Library, and you can add the function to your version.

For example, create a file named "CustomSeleniumLibrary.py", and make it look like this:

```
# CustomSeleniumLibrary.py
from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library

class CustomSeleniumLibrary(Selenium2Library):
    def insert_into_prompt(self, text):
        alert = None
        try:
            alert = self._current_browser().switch_to_alert()
            alert.send_keys(text)

        except WebDriverException:
            raise RuntimeError('There were no alerts')
```

You can then write a test case which uses that library like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | CustomSeleniumLibrary.py
| Suite Teardown | Close All Browsers

*** test cases ***
| Example of typing into a prompt
| | Open Browser | http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt
| | Select Frame | iframeResult
| | Click Button | Try it
| | Insert into prompt | my name is Inigo Montoya
| | Confirm action
```

Answer (score 3):

Think it's worth pointing out that this keyword exists now (since SeleniumLibrary 3.0), so there's no longer any need to use a custom script/library.
http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Input%20Text%20Into%20Alert