# How to input text in the pop-up window of browser using Robot Framework

Tags: automation, robotframework

Hi is there a way to interact(add text, click button) with the pop-up window of browser using Robot framework?

[See sample pop-up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXHde.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried to use input text into alert keyword but it's not working. im not sure if there's available keyword / library that i can use to interact with pop-ups.

Comment: I would recommend writing your own keyword to handle this could be of use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543666/how-to-handle-prompt-box-with-robot-framework

Comment: Can you share the DOM?

Comment: That's not an alert ("pop-up"), this looks like authentication box - which is beyond selenium control. Try passing the user:pass in the url, this still works for some systems.